# php - check whether string end with image extension

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to verify string whether the string is image file name.

```
$aaa = 'abskwlfd.png';

if ($aaa is image file) {
echo 'it's image';
else {
echo 'not image';
}
```

How do i do that? It will chck 100 images, so it should be fast. I know there is a filetype verification method, but I think that's slow.. What about preg_match? Is it faster?
I'm not good at preg_match.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See also: [PHP how can i check if a file is mp3 or image file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file) or [How to check if an uploaded file is an image without mime type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484307/how-to-check-if-an-uploaded-file-is-an-image-without-mime-type)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$supported_image = array(
    'gif',
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png'
);

$src_file_name = 'abskwlfd.PNG';
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($src_file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Using strtolower to overcome case sensitive
if (in_array($ext, $supported_image)) {
    echo "it's image";
} else {
    echo 'not image';
}
?>
```

Comment: It won't work with "abskwlfd.PNG". Should use `strtolower` to ensure case-insensitive.

Comment: @invisal Thanks for pointing out, `strtolower` added in answer

Comment: This repo has a list of possible image extensions, https://github.com/arthurvr/image-extensions/blob/master/image-extensions.json

Answer (score 14):

try this code,

```
if (preg_match('/(\.jpg|\.png|\.bmp)$/i', $aaa)) {
   echo "image";
} else{
   echo "not image";
}
```

Comment: This is very clean, but I realized preg_match is slower than the method using pathinfo for multiple images processing..

Comment: very simple and helpful

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
function isImageFile($file) {
    $info = pathinfo($file);
    return in_array(strtolower($info['extension']), 
                    array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "bmp"));
}
```

- I am using `pathinfo` to retrieve detail information about file including extension.
- I am using `strtolower` to ensure that the extension will match our list of supported image  even it is in different case
- Using `in_array` to check whether file extension is in our list of image extenion.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 $allowed = array(
    '.jpg',
    '.jpeg',
    '.gif',
    '.png',
    '.flv'
    );
   if (!in_array(strtolower(strrchr($inage_name, '.')), $allowed)) {
     print_r('error message');
    }else {
       echo "correct image";
    }
```

or [strrchr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) it takes last occurence of character string..
else some other concept.

```
$allowed = array(
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/x-png',
                'image/gif',
                'application/x-shockwave-flash'
                        );
        if (!in_array($image_name, $allowed)) {
         print_r('error message');
        }else {
           echo "correct image";
        }
```

Here you can used [STRTOLOWER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function and also used [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$a=pathinfo("example.exe");

var_dump($a['extension']);//returns exe
```

Comment: Very simple, but how do i use it to if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, regex is the way to go. Alternatively, you could split around the `"."` and check the last element in the returned array against an array of image extensions. I'm not a PHP guy so I can't write the code for you, but I can write the regex:

`^[a-zA-Z\.0-9_-]+\.([iI][mM][gG]|[pP][nN][gG]|etc....)$`

This one is fairly simple. I know you don't have much experience with regex, but here's what this one does:

```
^: start of string
[a-zA-Z\.0-9_-]: describes range of characters including all letters, numbers, and ._-
\.: "." character
([iI][mM][gG]|[pP][nN][gG]|etc....): | means or. So just put all image extensions you know here. Again, the brackets for case-insensitivity
```

if you want to match any sequence then instead of the stuff in the brackets and the +, just use:

`.*`

"." matches any character and "*" means any amount of it. So this just basically says "no restrictions" (except newlines)

There are probably a lot of other things I'm missing, as you can see in the comments. Just read those, look at a regex reference, and you'll be fine.

Comment: A small correct: "you could split around the `"."` and check the **last element**"

Comment: Files name aren't limited to `[a-zA-Z\.0-9_-]`...

Comment: True, but it's OS-relative. Those are the ones that will almost certainly be in every OS.

Comment: It's fine if you aren't worried about integrity (and don't have spaces, commas, etc.). `pathinfo()` is better and much easier.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know much about PHP. If there's a better regex you know then I'd be glad to add it.

Comment: Something like `.*\.(img|png|gif|etc)` I guess, all that matters are the last bits. But I wouldn't bother with regex, there are even string manipulation methods that are simpler. Sorry, I don't like the answer.

Comment: And you need to make sure that extension is case-insensitive. ".PNG", ".png", ".Png", ".PNg", ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

use [pathinfo():](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); case sensitive
if (in_array($ext, $supported_image)) {
    echo "it's image";
} else {
    echo 'not image';
}
```

Comment: Who said it was an upload? The way this is written, the image will show an error for every file extension it doesn't have.